# Unexpected behavior when the constraints are applied for the first time

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, swift5

I want to change the layout and constraints relative to the orientation of the device.
Here's how I implemented it:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        setupViews()
        addViews()
        constraintSubviews()
}
func constraintSubviews() {
        if UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait {
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(portraitConstrains)
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(landscapeConstrains)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(nowPlayingView.portraitConstrains)
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(nowPlayingView.landscapeConstrains)
            

            
        } else {
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(portraitConstrains)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(landscapeConstrains)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(nowPlayingView.landscapeConstrains)
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(nowPlayingView.portraitConstrains)
           
        }
}
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        constraintSubviews()
}
```

Here's what I ended up when running the code:

[image]

And this is what I expect:

[image]

I can't get the layout I designed in the code unless I change device orientation once.

[image]

**Better implementation**

I've searched all over the Internet and the best thing I found was this implementation. Is there a better implementation regarding this subject?

Answer (score 2):

You need

1- Make deactivate before activate

```
func constraintSubviews() {
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait {
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(landscapeConstrains) 
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(nowPlayingView.landscapeConstrains)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(nowPlayingView.portraitConstrains) 
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(portraitConstrains) 
    } else {
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(portraitConstrains) 
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(nowPlayingView.portraitConstrains)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(landscapeConstrains)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(nowPlayingView.landscapeConstrains) 
    }
}
```

2- Replace

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    constraintSubviews()
}
```

with

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.willTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    constraintSubviews()
}
```

Comment: What about `traitCollectionDidChange` instead of `viewWillTransition`?

Comment: Upvoted, but I have a question. Why not use `viewDidLayoutSubviews`? (That's what I use, with a flag to prevent useless CPU cycles.) Does `viewWillTransition` work in all cases? As for the OP question in the comments, you should probably note that size classes are **extremely** odd on iPads in full screen and somethings in split screen, and on certain iPhone models too.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't solve the problem.